# Install RVM with the latest Ruby (2.0.0) and Rails (3.2.13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

when adding this in terminal

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
```

I get:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    330      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   488
100   422  100   422    0     0    198      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  6115
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 2: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
Julios-MacBook-Pro:~ jsalvat$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    420      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   512
100   422  100   422    0     0    244      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3907
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 2: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
```

and rvm is not install nor is ruby 2.0.0 and yes I am new at all this if someone can help me it would be great thanks!

Comment: I guess, `please try again`.  I just tried your command it works fine for me.

Comment: please check with `--debug` - if it does not give any more extra useful information provide the log of using installer with `--trace` flag - which shows all the internal details.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in addition to comments and to show you proper formatting here is the line from https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for `--autolibs` modes:

```
4, enable, enabled - Install missing package manager (only OSX, on Linux it's like 3).
```

Please go through the docs.  Why are you explicitly specifying `--autolibs=enable`.  You don't need to do that because `enable` is the default mode.

So, you should just do the following:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Comment: when I do :\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
I get: 
Error: /Users/jsalvat/.rvmrc is for rvm settings only.
rvm CLI may NOT be called from within /Users/jsalvat/.rvmrc.
Skipping the loading of /Users/jsalvat/.rvmrc
Julios-MacBook-Pro:~ jsalvat$